# IC not getting the same power input

Tags: power-supply, pcb, circuit-analysis, dc, circuit-design

I have two different PCB boards. One is a sensor board and the other is a power board.

I connect a 9V battery to the power board, to a 7805 5V regulator, and through a filtering process of some capacitors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs3cas.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I measure the voltage with the two boards separated I get 5V and everything is fine.

However, when I connect the power output via a flat flexible cable to the sensor board, the input drops from 5V to 0.5V on the sensor board and the LED starts dimming, and thus my sensor board does not work!

I checked on a breakout board and the cable can handle up to 30V.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I can add the sensor board if its relevant. But it will take me a while to draw the schematic.

Comment: Have you checked for a short circuit? How much is the current draw for the other board?

Comment: Is the 9V battery capable of supplying the current required by your sensor board?  Is the 7805 overheating and shutting down?

Comment: Sounds like there's a short circuit on the sensor board. Unless the sensor board works by itself?

Comment: @Justme yes, i checked using a continuity test for the whole board before and after soldering the components.

Comment: @user253751 the sensor board has been fully checked.

Comment: Does the power *only* droop on the sensor board, or does it droop on both boards?  If the former, then you've got high resistance in your cable or its connectors.  If the latter, then you're asking too much of either the battery or (probably) the regulator.

Comment: Well, it definitely *sounds* like your sensor board has a short and you didn't see it when you checked. It could be something else, but that is most likely.

Comment: @TimWescott it drops on both boards

Comment: @user253751 my original through hole design, which definitely does not have a short got the same issue when the power circuit attached.

Comment: Again, how much current do the boards take in total?

Comment: What is the ESR of your inductor, L1? HOW MUCH CURRENT DOES THE SENSOR BOARD DRAW?

Comment: Is the voltage dropping at the battery, at the output of the 7805, or at the output end of the inductor?

Comment: @Justme Well, calculating on absolute maximum ratings of the datasheets; its around 250mA-300mA

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  Maximum DC Resistance: 8 Ohms

Comment: @TimWescott battery voltage drops to about 7v when the boards are connected. the output of the 7805 drops to about 3.5v, and the inductor is the same as the 7805.
Without the connection, 9v battery, 5.2 7805 and same for the inductor

Comment: it is a  TO-220 package and the datasheet states that it can handle up to 1.5Amps with a load regulation of 50mV at 250mA-750mA

Comment: Yes, the regulator could handle amps, but the battery can't provide them.

Comment: If the inductor has an ESR of 8 ohms you will see a voltage drop of 2.4V across it when passing 300mA. The inductor's ESR is about 100x bigger than what you should have.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson i see around 1.5v when i connected the PC power supply, output up to 2A @ 5v

Answer (score 0):

Your load is drawing too much current (250mA) that the weak 9V battery can't provide. Battery voltage drops to about 7V and 7805 type of regulators need more than 7V to stay within normal operation. So as there is not enough voltage at regulator input, the regulator stops working properly.

Comment: Some data to quantify the "to much current" for "the weak 9V battery under the assumption that a block battery is used: https://www.powerstream.com/9V-Alkaline-tests.htm

Comment: @Justme i have a PC power supply, i connected Vsb which can output up to 2A current @ 5v to the power board and the voltage measured on Vcc and Vdd on the sensor board is still 0.5v

Comment: Where did you connect the PC power supply 5V? To the regulator input side? Or to the regulator output side to power the boards? You really should measure what voltages are present at which points, to see where the voltage drop happens.

Comment: Instead of the battery so yeah to the 7805 in and gnd.

Comment: It makes no sense to give 5V to 7805 input, it does not work with 5V on input. Much less if there is a diode in between to drop the voltage to 4.3 before it reaches regulator input. In this case, you should turn the ATX power supply on and feed 12V to regulator, but given the issues that are still not resolved, it could cause something to break so perhaps it would not be wise at the moment.

Comment: @forthelulx sorry I don't see what vcc and vdd and IC you mean, I am not a mind reader. Can you be more specific and draw a picture, and consider this being a new question instead of continuing here with new questions.